# How to set alert cancel on Popup In selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, alert

I'm new to Selenium webdriver. Can someone help me how to make alert cancel for below code

```html
<div id="popup1" class="k-window-content k-content" style="" data-role="window" tabindex="0" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="popup1_wnd_title">
<div class="popupWrap">
          Policy violation                        
<div class="wrap-keyword">
          Note                         
<textarea id="flagtxtnote" cols="50" rows="4"/>
<fieldset class="full-width">
<input id="btnflagcancel" class="more gray-theme" type="button" value="Flag" onclick="saveclick(4, 0);"/>
<input id="btnflagsave" class="more icon-hat" type="button" value="Flag" onclick="saveclick(4, 1);"/>
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried below code

```
    try 
    {
        //Handle the alert pop-up using seithTO alert statement
        Alert alert = dr.switchTo().alert();

        //Print alert is present
        System.out.println("Alert is present");

        //get the message which is present on pop-up
        String message = alert.getText();

        //print the pop-up message
        System.out.println(message);

        alert.sendKeys("");
        //Click on OK button on pop-up
        alert.accept();
    } 
    catch (NoAlertPresentException e) 
    {
        //if alert is not present print message
        System.out.println("alert is not present");
    }
```

Output Its showing (alert is not present)

Comment: What do you refer to as "alert"? A real alert/popup that browser displays (and which is modal), or a `<div id="popup1"` in the HTML you posted?

If you have a real alert, we cannot see it in the code you posted, so it's hard to say anything.
If you mean `<div id="popup1"`, then it's not really an alert/popup, just a div styled to look like a popup. Instead of using Alert with it you should treat it like any normal html UI (e.g. `browser. findElementByXpath("//input[@id='btnflagcancel']").click()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you given code is working fine